# How to properly work with typescript projects

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

We are working on multiple typescript projects using vscode, and we are not sure whats the best with to work with them, right now we have a tasks.json configured like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "windows": {
        "command": "\"./node_modules/.bin/tsc\""
    },
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-w", "-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
}
```

But doing it this way we have to start the task with `cmd+shift+b` every time we open a project.

Is there a way to have this started automatically?

It doesn't have to be using `task.json` it can be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box, but you can use the plugin [Blade Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yukidoi.blade-runner) which will execute your build command every time you open a folder.